# display video in react native project with expo

Tags: react-native, video, expo

Im trying to display a video on screen in my react native project (with expo).
I put the video inside the project, and I see the message :

**The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding**

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you want to open video file in your `VS project` or in `react-native` App? Because in VScode they have restriction on opening large dataset files and throw this error.(generally)

Comment: For now, I just want to display a video that is located in VS project to display it my app (with expo)

Comment: For that you can follow this post: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-play-video-with-react-native-and-expo-30523bfcb311

Comment: I saw this link, even if I copy paste the code, I have an error : 
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `VideoScreen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sidverma pointed out, this is a VS Code related error.

**You cannot open large files inside the editor as it might crash.**

I remember opening large bin files a long time ago with other editors and it would freeze my computer!

**Anyhow, you can still use that file inside your React Native application. This is just your editor being careful about opening large files.**

Comment: You mean, even if I saw this message, I can open the video on my application?

Answer (score 0):

If want to use Video in `react-native` take help of this library: `react-native-video`

```
 import Video from "react-native-video";

<View>
        <Video
          source={require("./../assets/video1.mp4")}
          style={styles.backgroundVideo}
          muted={true}
          repeat={true}
          resizeMode={"cover"}
          rate={1.0}
          ignoreSilentSwitch={"obey"}
        />
</View>
```

Alternative: [Expo LINK](https://snack.expo.io/@sidverma32/video)

Comment: But can I use this library with expo also?

Comment: Yes, but if you don't want to try outside the library then you can check this in expo: https://snack.expo.io/@sidverma32/video

Comment: I tried this, but I receive the error : Error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTVideoInstance.Contants' )

Comment: I saw that I have to do react-native link react-native-video but it does not work for me.. Do you have an idea..?

Comment: Did you tried the expo snack link or checked with your code? Better share code snippet how you are trying to implement.